# ionic calling restApi with header

Tags: ionic-framework

Everyone

I am new with ionic framework. When calling rest API with header field and passing token with header field. API always call twice one preflight request and second `POST`.

In preflight request I am getting `status code 204` and on `POST` it is working fine with status code 200. but when calling rest API without token it is calling only once

```
var head = { 'X-Auth-Token' : window.localStorage.getItem('token') };

this.getlist = function (json) { return post('restapi url',json); }; 

function post(targetUrl, json) { 
  var deferred = $q.defer(); 
  $http({ url: targetUrl, method: "POST", data: json, headers: head }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) { deferred.resolve(data); })     
  return deferred.promise; 
}
```

Comment: Post some code that you have tried.

Comment: var head = {
      'X-Auth-Token' : window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    };

    this.getlist = function (json) {
      return post('restapi url',json);
    };
 
   function post(targetUrl, json) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({
        url: targetUrl,
  method: "POST",
  data: json,
  headers: head
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      return deferred.promise;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png

please see this image. this image have complete flow for preflight request

Answer (score 1):

If Request should not have any custom header parameter, 
If request header contains any custom header then browser will make pre-flight request, you cant avoid it